# C++ Builder paintbox, do not know how to use

Tags: user-interface, canvas, paint, c++builder, borland-c++

I would like to draw lines on paint box component which I put on the form.

My questions are:

1. In which func to implement it? am I should do it on FormPaint func or maybe on FormShow?
2. What paint box allow me to do? what is the power of paint box?

Answer (score 1):

1. Draw the PaintBox from the PaintBox's `OnPaint` handler.
2. I think the purpose of the PaintBox is obvious. It is a "lightweight" "windowless" control that you can use "to extend the `OnPaint` method of it's parent control" in more structured, isolated way (instead of putting all the drawing into the parent control's `OnPaint`).

By using a PaintBox instead of putting everything into the parent's `OnPaint` you immediately get some perks, for example: You can use the property editor to position/anchor/hide the drawing (insted of playing with messy offset calculations in the `OnPaint` of the parent). The very same properties can be used to elegantly manipulate the drawing at runtime. This results in less and more simple code because many problems are handled for you by the framework.

Comment: also provides Canvas accessible space for example if you have OpenGL on the client space you can add some info/preview area with Canvas this way easily ...